# WillPopScope not working after adding input in webview?

Tags: android, flutter, webview

I have tried to use the willpopscope functionality of flutter to enable back button functionality. However after I have inputted any text in the webview, it does not work until I tap somewhere else on the mobile screen. Here is the code,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:keyboard_visibility/keyboard_visibility.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';


void main()  {
runApp(MyApp());}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: WebViewWebPage(),
    );
  }
}
class WebViewWebPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _WebViewWebPageState createState() => _WebViewWebPageState();
}
class _WebViewWebPageState extends State<WebViewWebPage> {


  Future<bool> _onBack() async {

    bool goBack;
    print('AREARE');
    var value = await webView.canGoBack();  // check webview can go back

    if (value) {
      webView.goBack(); // perform webview back operation
      return false;
    } else {
      await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Confirmation ', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple)),
          // Are you sure?
          content: new Text('Do you want exit app ? '),
          // Do you want to go back?
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                setState(() {
                  goBack = false;
                });
              },
              child: new Text('No'), // No
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                setState(() {
                  goBack = true;
                });
              },
              child: new Text('Yes'), // Yes
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      if (goBack) Navigator.pop(context);   // If user press Yes pop the page
      return goBack;
    }
  }
  // URL to load
  var URL = "https://www.google.com";
  // Webview progress
  double progress = 0;
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  int counter=0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }
  void yo(){
  setState(() {
  counter++;
  });
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("JAM App"),
          ),
          body:  Container(

              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    (progress != 1.0)
                        ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                        value: progress,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                        valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightBlue[900]))
                        : null,    // Should be removed while showing

                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: WillPopScope(
                          onWillPop: _onBack,
                          child: InAppWebView(
                          initialUrl: URL,
                          initialHeaders: {},
                          //initialOptions: {},
                          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {

                            webView = controller;
                            print('\nWOOOOOOOOO\n');

                            final _blurNode = FocusNode();
                            final FocusNode roomIdInputFocusNode = FocusNode();
                            final roomIdHasFocus = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
                            roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(false);
                            roomIdInputFocusNode.addListener(() {
                              roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(roomIdInputFocusNode.hasFocus);

                            });

                            KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
                              onChange: (bool visible) {
                                if (!visible) {
                                 // roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(false);

                                  //FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

                                  //FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                                  /*while (currentFocus.canRequestFocus) {
                                    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                                  }*/
                                  //currentFocus.dispose();

                                  print('Salame');
                                  yo();
                                  /*bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent, RouteInfo info) {
                                    _onBack(); // Do some stuff.
                                    print('yyy');
                                    return true;
                                  }*/
                                  //BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
                                  // BuildContext context;
                                  // final renderObj = context.findRenderObject();
                                  // if (renderObj is RenderBox) {
                                  //   final hitTestResult = HitTestResult();
                                  //   if (renderObj.hitTest(hitTestResult, position:  Offset(0,0))) {
                                  //     // a descendant of `renderObj` got tapped
                                  //     print('yikes');
                                  //     print(hitTestResult.path);
                                  //   }
                                  // }

                                } else if (visible && roomIdInputFocusNode.hasFocus) {
                                  roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(true);
                                  print('Namaste');
                                }
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          /*onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                            // Listen Url change
                            /*if(URL == LISTENINGURL){
                              Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                                  .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => new SecondPage()));
                            }*/
                          },*/
                          onProgressChanged:
                              (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                            setState(() {
                              this.progress = progress / 100;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ].where((Object o) => o != null).toList())),
    );  //Remove null widgets
  }
}
```

I have tried to intercept the event of Keyboard popup and unfocus the text field after the keyboard is closed, but that also didn't restore the back button.

EDIT: For some reason when I remove scaffold it works as I require it to. However, I really want to include scaffold otherwise I can't use any of the features of material app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
return WillPopScope(
```

and as child of that you must insert your Scaffold.

This way may work.

```
return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _onBack,
      child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("JAM App"),
      ),
      body:  Container(

          child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                (progress != 1.0)
                    ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: progress,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.lightBlue[900]))
                    : null,    // Should be removed while showing

                Expanded(
                  child: Container(
                      child: InAppWebView(
                      initialUrl: URL,
                      initialHeaders: {},
                      //initialOptions: {},
                      onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {

                        webView = controller;
                        print('\nWOOOOOOOOO\n');

                        final _blurNode = FocusNode();
                        final FocusNode roomIdInputFocusNode = FocusNode();
                        final roomIdHasFocus = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
                        roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(false);
                        roomIdInputFocusNode.addListener(() {
                          roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(roomIdInputFocusNode.hasFocus);

                        });

                        KeyboardVisibilityNotification().addNewListener(
                          onChange: (bool visible) {
                            if (!visible) {
                             // roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(false);

                              //FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();

                              //FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);
                              /*while (currentFocus.canRequestFocus) {
                                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                              }*/
                              //currentFocus.dispose();

                              print('Salame');
                              yo();
                              /*bool myInterceptor(bool stopDefaultButtonEvent, RouteInfo info) {
                                _onBack(); // Do some stuff.
                                print('yyy');
                                return true;
                              }*/
                              //BackButtonInterceptor.add(myInterceptor);
                              // BuildContext context;
                              // final renderObj = context.findRenderObject();
                              // if (renderObj is RenderBox) {
                              //   final hitTestResult = HitTestResult();
                              //   if (renderObj.hitTest(hitTestResult, position:  Offset(0,0))) {
                              //     // a descendant of `renderObj` got tapped
                              //     print('yikes');
                              //     print(hitTestResult.path);
                              //   }
                              // }

                            } else if (visible && roomIdInputFocusNode.hasFocus) {
                              roomIdHasFocus.sink.add(true);
                              print('Namaste');
                            }
                          },
                        );
                      },
                      /*onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                        // Listen Url change
                        /*if(URL == LISTENINGURL){
                          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => new SecondPage()));
                        }*/
                      },*/
                      onProgressChanged:
                          (InAppWebViewController controller, int progress) {
                        setState(() {
                          this.progress = progress / 100;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ].where((Object o) => o != null).toList())),
                    ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input Emanuele, I'd already tried that and it hadn't worked

Answer (score 0):

normally in webview we need to dispose the webview to move to other pages to flutter. I dont know if it'll work but pls try to dispose the webview..

Comment: But my application requires to opened as a webview.

Answer (score 0):

use flutter 3.0,this problem will be solved!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).